# Extending a TypeScript class with multiple generic parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux, typescript-generics

i try to extend a React Component Class with generic Parameters but I cannot get it working. According to the TypeScript Docs and this [TypeScript Class Generic Parameter Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338771/typescript-class-generic-parameter-constraints), and this [extending a class with a generic T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974237/extending-a-class-with-a-generic-t) I ended up in the following (not working) code:

**Base Class:**

```js
class BaseView<P, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    public constructor(props: P, state: S) {
        super(props, state);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => {
    console.log('store', store);
    return {
        store
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    console.log('dispatch', dispatch);
    return {
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)((BaseView as any));

export function subclass<P, S>(c): BaseView<P, S> {
    return c;
}
```

**The class which extends the Base Class**:

I tried different ways, using the factory like this:

```
export class Documents extends subclass(BaseView)<DocumentsProperties, DocumentsState> { 
// this leads into ""BaseView<{}, {}>" is no constructor function type
```

or without using the factory:

```
export class Documents extends BaseView<DocumentsProperties, DocumentsState> { 
// no base constructor has the specified number of type arguments
```

I also tried out several other ways but i feel like i was programming for the first time of my life....I cannot get it running for multiple Parameters. What am I missing here?

greetings Messerbill

Comment: The former doesn't work because you want `subclass()` to return `typeof BaseView` and not `BaseView<P,S>`.  I don't understand why the latter doesn't work, though.  I can't reproduce your error in the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//).  Can you reproduce the error in a self-contained (no libraries) example?  If not you'll have to wait for someone with react installed in their environment

Comment: What are you expecting `c` to be? I'm guessing you want `c` to be some super constructor. Is it React?

Comment: @MinusFour yes it is react. I expected c to be a BaseView "Type" - not an instance. I also tried using `new c()` which did not work either

Comment: @messerbill have you tried `(c : { new() : BaseView<P,S> })` for both `c` and the return type.

Comment: Higher-order components like `connect` and generic components do not mix easily.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573647) for the approach I recommend.  Let me know if you have trouble applying it to your scenario.

Comment: thank you for your advises....at least I could not get it running the way i wanted to. I now have my generic BaseView without the high order component (`connect()`). So i Have to call the connect method in each of those components....